# Need to get the customer wise sales record with current date and previous date

Tags: sql

The requirement is to get the customer sales record with current date and previous date.  Can anyone help me to get the data using SQL.

The below table is Source:

```
Name    Order   Sales date
Ann     1       13/01/2017
Ann     3       26/01/2017
Ann     6       14/03/2017
Ben     2       16/01/2017
Ben     5       21/02/2017
Cavin   4       15/03/2017
```

The target should be as

```
Name    Order   latest_sales_date   previous_sales_date
Ann     1       13/01/2017  
Ann     3       26/01/2017          13/01/2017
Ann     6       14/03/2017          26/01/2017
Ben     2       16/01/2017  
Ben     5       21/02/2017          16/01/2017
Cavin   4       15/03/2017
```

Comment: You should tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Just a suggestion, avoid using reserved words as table or column names (eg `Name` and `Order`)

Answer (score 1):

Use the ANSI standard `lag()` function:

```
select t.*,
       lag(sales_date) over (partition by name order by sales_date) as prev_sales_date
from t;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Oracle, Postgres or SQL server 2012 onwards:

```
select t1.Name, t1.Order, t1.Sales_date as latest_sale, 
       lag(t1.Sales_Date) over (partition by t1.Name order by t1.Order) as previous_sales_date
from MyTable t1
```